# SQL Server : Compare same string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query say

```
select details,* from employee
```

`details` column value can like **'very good,very good, bad'**. It can have any number of *comma separated values*.

I want to compare text that falls between each commas and remove duplicates.

Result needs to be like **'very good,bad'**

How can i implement it. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't store data as comma separated values. It will only cause you lots of trouble.

Comment: actually we are not storing in comma separated way. I used it in order to explain problem in simpler way. Actually, i am generating it from multiple table using stuff

Comment: then you just need `select distinct details` or some such

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result. All as formatted text, not images.

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? 2016 or later?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have create a scalar valued function **fn_RemoveDuplicate** which takes varchar as input and return a varchar (having no duplicates).

You can then use it as

> select dbo.fn_RemoveDuplicate(details),* from employee

```
Create FUNCTION fn_RemoveDuplicate 
(
    @inputstring varchar(max)
)
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN


declare @test2 varchar(max)
declare @test1 xml =cast(@inputstring as xml) 


SET @test2 ='<Details>'+ cast(('<detail><value1>'+replace(@inputstring,',' ,'</value1></detail><detail><value1>')+'</value1></detail>') as varchar(max))+'</Details>'
set @test1=cast(@test2 as xml)

DECLARE @Details varchar(max)
SET @Details = NULL

SELECT @Details = COALESCE(@Details + ',','') + [value1]
FROM (select distinct
    t.x.value('value1[1]','Varchar(50)') as value1     
from @test1.nodes('/Details/detail') t(x)) as p


return @Details

END
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use **SQL Server 2016 or later** the following answer solve your problem:

```
select
    e.*,
    x.[expected_result]
from
    employee e
cross apply
    (select
    stuff((
            select
            distinct
                ','+ltrim(rtrim(value))
            from
                string_split(e.details, ',')
            for xml path('')) 
        ,1 ,1 ,'')  as [expected_result]) as x
```

I solve it by using `string_split()` and `stuff()` functions. The following link helps you to understand how they work:

[STRING_SPLIT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[STUFF (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

[SQL Server CROSS APPLY and OUTER APPLY](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1958/sql-server-cross-apply-and-outer-apply/)

Storing data with comma separated value is not a good practice. I also strongly suggest you to change the model if it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

The idea for the solution is to use a table valued function (fn_SplitString), and combine the resultant table based on distinct values.

The following query should do what you want:

```
SELECT
    [ID],[Details],
    [cleansedDetails] = (SELECT
    STUFF((
            SELECT
            DISTINCT ','+LTRIM(RTRIM(ISNULL(ncValue,cvalue)))
            FROM
                fn_SplitString([Details], ',')
            FOR XML PATH('')) 
        ,1 ,1 ,''))
FROM [dbo].[tb_Employee]
```

In this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=a559e40825894af9de624de41d5852ca), you could find the DDL & DML for my example data and the definition for the table valued function fn_SplitString. You could check how the code works in different scenarios.